# Active NavLink with Reactstrap and React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, reactstrap

I'm building the navbar component for my application but I'm having problems with the activeClassName prop. It doesn't change any class or style when i change between the Links. I've tried everything I saw on Internet with no results. Maybe someone can give me an advice with this issue.

My imports:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink as RRNavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Nav, NavItem, NavLink } from 'reactstrap';
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
    <Nav className="navbar-logged">
      <NavItem>
        <NavLink
          className="nav-link-gdc"
          activeClassName="active"
          to="/home"
          tag={RRNavLink}
        >
            INICIO
        </NavLink>
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem>
        <NavLink
          className="nav-link-gdc"
          activeClassName="active"
          to="/secondLink"
          tag={RRNavLink}
        >
            secondLink
        </NavLink>
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem>
        <NavLink
          className="nav-link-gdc"
          activeClassName="active"
          to="/thirdLink"
          tag={RRNavLink}
        >
            thirdLink
        </NavLink>
      </NavItem>
    </Nav>
```

Thank You

Comment: Hi Alberto, did you find the solution for this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Nope, I focused on the rest of the project but I'm getting to its final so I'll have to face this problem soon. I think it might have something to do with redux but I'm just talking for talking sake. I'll get to you if I find the solution

Comment: Hey, I found the solution. Check it here https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-views-arent-updating-when-something-changes-outside-of-redux

You need to do something like this export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, null, null, {pure: false}
)(Component);

Comment: I mean you need to add the {pure: false} to the connect function of the component that has your NavLink

Comment: You're the man!! Hey, post the solution if you want so I can give you the correct answer

Comment: Sure, I will add the answer for other developers who struggled with this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible reason is that you are using Redux to manage application's state

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-views-arent-updating-when-something-changes-outside-of-redux

> If your views depend on global state or React “context”, you might
>   find that views decorated with connect() will fail to update.
>
> This is because connect() implements shouldComponentUpdate by default,
>   assuming that your component will produce the same results given the
>   same props and state. This is a similar concept to React’s
>   PureRenderMixin.

The fastest (***not the best***) solution for this is to pass the pure: false option to connect() function of the component that has your NavLink(s) (in my case it's the Header)

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { test: state.test}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, {
  pure: false
})(Header)
```

> This will remove the assumption that Header is pure and cause it to
>   update whenever its parent component renders. Note that this will make
>   your application less performant, so only do this if you have no other
>   option.